# Building dlib on Google colab using CMake

Tags: cmake, google-colaboratory, dlib

I am trying to install dlib on Google colaboratory (Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)), but it's throwing an error.

**CMake Error:**

```
The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "dlib" in directory /content/dlib/dlib
CUDA_curand_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "dlib" in directory /content/dlib/dlib
cusolver (ADVANCED)
linked by target "dlib" in directory /content/dlib/dlib

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/content/dlib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/content/dlib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

For full details, please visit this link:
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1529

Google colab already has these libraries in `/usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`.

How do I link this path to CMake, so that it can find these libraries?

Here is the Google colab link to reproduce the error. Please note that you will need to download the cudnn file from developer.nvidia.com. You will need to sign-in, but the file can be freely downloaded. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IiOLDP20QT3JFx5pigCibDadq9orNErk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dlib is now pre-installed on colab, so you might be unblocked with simply:

```
import dlib
help(dlib)
```

Comment: I have checked the Google Colab, the command 'dlib.cuda.get_num_devices()' is giving output 1 and the command 'dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA' is giving output 'False', which means dlib is recognizing GPU but not using cuda on google colab.

Comment: Ugh, you're right; edited my answer to reflect the necessary workaround.

Comment: Workaround is no longer needed (might have to [reset all runtimes] once if you're still assigned an old VM).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is working now. The workarounds you have posted earlier enabled dlib to use cuda, but, during execution dlib's cnn detector wasn't working. Now, I don't need to make any changes and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

install on GCP Ubuntu20.04 Machine type n2d-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 32 GB memory)

```
git clone https://github.com/Universe-ML21/script_install_dlib.git
sudo chmod +x script_install_dlib/auto_dlib.sh
bash script_install_dlib/auto_dlib.sh
```